# Splice removes more than one index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making my own filter system for filtering data, and I'm building the basic functionality now, such as adding and removing filters.

Adding filters works fine, but when I play around with adding and removing, sometimes `splice` removes more than one filter. Why is it doing that? here is my code:

```
    var active_filters = [];

    var available_filters = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'city'
    ];

    var filters = {
        first_name: {
            title: 'First Name',
            is_active: false,
            types: [
                {
                    input: 'text'
                },

                {
                    input: 'select',
                    options: [
                        'asc', 'desc'
                    ],
                    values: [
                        'Ascending', 'Descending'
                    ]
                }
            ],

        },

        last_name: {
            title: 'Last Name',
            is_active: false,
            types: [
                {
                    input: 'text'
                },

                {
                    input: 'select',
                    options: [
                        'asc', 'desc'
                    ],
                    values: [
                        'Ascending', 'Descending'
                    ]
                }
            ],

        },

        city: {
            title: 'City',
            is_active: false,
            types: [
                {
                    input: 'text'
                },
            ],

        },
    };

    var id_filters = $("#filters");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        id_filters.html(template_filters(filters));
    });

    function template_filters(filters) {
        var html = '<select class="select_filters" id="select_filters" onchange="add_filter();">';

        html += '<option value="0">Select Filter</option>';

        for (var property in filters)
        {
            if (filters.hasOwnProperty(property))
            {
                var title = filters[property].title;
                var is_active = filters[property].is_active;
                var types = filters[property].types;

                html += '<option value="'+property+'">'+title+'</option>';
            }
        }

        html += '</select>';

        return html;
    }

    function template_show_filter(filter, filter_name)
    {
        var html = '<div id="filter-'+filter_name+'" class="div_filter">';

        html += '<span>'+filter.title+' <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove_filter(\''+filter_name+'\')">X</a></span>';

        html += '</div>';
        return html;
    }

    function add_filter()
    {
        var select_filters = $("#select_filters");
        var selected_filter = select_filters.val();

        if (selected_filter != 0)
        {
            if (active_filters.length == 0)
            {
                active_filters.push(selected_filter);
                id_filters.append(template_show_filter(filters[selected_filter], selected_filter));
            }
            else
            {
                if (active_filters.indexOf(selected_filter) === -1)
                {
                    active_filters.push(selected_filter);
                    id_filters.append(template_show_filter(filters[selected_filter], selected_filter));
                }
            }


        }
    }

    function remove_filter(filter_name)
    {
        var index = active_filters.indexOf(filter_name);



        if (index >= 0)
        {
            var id = $("#filter-"+filter_name);
            id.remove();

            active_filters.splice(index); // here, it removes more than one
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please have a look at [MDN web docs – `Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

If you want to remove only one item, you should call `.splice(index, 1)`.

If you don’t specify the second argument, “then all of the elements beginning with start index on through the end of the array will be deleted.”

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are splicing at index.

```
active_filters.splice(index);
```

This will remove all elements after the index value.